# Error filterStart on tomcat when using java 1.6

Tags: java, tomcat

Let me start with what I use:
- ubuntu 11.04
- apache-tomcat-6.0.33

some details on my java:

```
adam@adam-1215N:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

adam@adam-1215N:~$ ll /usr/lib/jvm
total 84
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2011-08-28 10:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 229 root root 69632 2011-08-28 13:13 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 2011-08-27 21:03 default-java -> java-6-openjdk/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 2011-08-27 21:03 java-1.6.0-openjdk -> java-6-openjdk/
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 2011-08-27 21:11 java-6-openjdk/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2164 2011-06-11 11:07 .java-6-openjdk.jinfo
```

How I deploy an application:
I build it using `mvn clean install`. Then I extract the content of created .war file and copy it to my directory in `webapps` in tomcat. It worked initially.

Now, the meritum:
Project that I try to deploy is quite simple. Everything worked until I wanted one method to return Set of objects. When building I got error that generics are not supported in java 1.3. I googled, and found that I need to add `maven-compiler-plugin` to my pom.xml pointing which java I want to use. So I added, pointing at 1.6. And here it comes:

```
Aug 28, 2011 6:25:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/myproject]
Aug 28, 2011 6:25:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 28, 2011 6:25:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/myproject] startup failed due to previous errors
```

**Now the bad news**
I tried to return to initial maven configuration, deleted generics that made me use java 1.6 and problem still exists... I was messing with jdk, installing and removing different versions, that is why I gave you same details on what I have in the beginning.

Tomcat also gives one more warning, I thought it is irrelevant but I didn't see it before (or didn't notice) so I'm putting it here:

```
Aug 28, 2011 6:15:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
```

I'm confused and tired, after fighting with it almost 2 days. Any help appreciated.

**Edit**
I have found reason: I have changed name of class that was referenced in web.xml and "Refactor" tool in Eclipse didn't change it.
Leaving it here in case someone find it useful :)

Comment: There should be a stacktrace after the "SEVERE: Context [/myproject] startup failed due to previous errors". Could you post that?

The warning about the Apache Tomcat Native library is irrelevant to your problem.

Also, there is usually no need to extract the contents of the WAR file, just place the whole WAR file into the webapps folder. Tomcat will take care of extracting and deploying it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no stacktrace after that. Or maybe it is, but in another file. Or can I change the debug level for tomcat somewhere?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. Following your question I found another log file, which had stacktrace, and immediately I found a reason. I changed name of class that was referenced in web.xml and the exception was `ClassNotFoundException`. So much wasted time just because refactoring in eclipse didn't find that... :)

Comment: The classic CNFE, glad you fixed it :) Could you post an answer to your own question and accept it so it gets closed?

Comment: I've just added it, but I it says I can accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked up in `logs/localhost.2011-08-28.log` and found `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` which led me to web.xml containing reference to class that I had renamed

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when deploying a spring mvc app from eclipse.  The maven build included all the dependent jars for spring under WEB-INF/lib and that worked fine when deployed to Tomcat.  The eclipse Indigo export-war functionality was not exporting the dependent spring jars presumably because of the maven directory structure, even though it was in the build path and all the jars were displayed under the Libraries tag.